# Cropping an image using openCV

Tags: c++, design-patterns, opencv, pattern-matching

I'm trying pattern recognition using OpenCV.

In this process, I'm taking a photograph of a paper. And it should crop the paper alone, eliminating the extra portion. Or at least, I've to draw the border to the page.

Is there any algorithm.? Please help :)

PS : I'm unable to upload a sample screenshot. Can anyone tell me how to do that.? So that the requirement would be clear enough. :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you have tried but...

In order to crop an image using OpenCV you can follow the instructions in [this SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14365411/opencv-crop-image)

In order to detect a piece of paper and try it out on the square detection then you can follow [This SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8667818/opencv-c-obj-c-detecting-a-sheet-of-paper-square-detection)

Not sure what else I can add into this question to help you, there is detecting the paper, then cropping the image. Obviously once you have detected the paper you will need to take the four corners that it detects, create Width and height and plumb that into your cropping function.

Good Luck

G./

P.S @William was right, it is helpful if you add in what you have tried & what implementation style you are aiming for, it helps to create more accurate useful questions for you & the community

Spelling corrected