# Opencv compare Rects

Tags: opencv, rect, mat

I get a vector of Rect by calling DetectMultiScale:

```
face_cascade.detectMultiScale(ImgGray,faces,1.1,2,0|CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE);
```

But Compare requires Mat:

```
compare(OriginalImg,roi,dist,CMP_EQ);
```

How do I convert Rect to Mat to make the comparison or is there a way to compare Rects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to compare 2 images, your `compare` function take 2 cv::Mat as firsts inputs.
To take the roi from your `ImgGray` you have to extract a new Mat from the ROI given by `detectMultiScale`

```
Mat ImgGray;
vector<Rect> faces;
face_cascade.detectMultiScale(ImgGray,faces,1.1,2,0|CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE);
Rect roiRect = faces[0];
Mat roi = ImgGray (roiRect);
compare(OriginalImg,roi,dist,CMP_EQ);
```

`OriginalImg`, `dist` and `roi` have the same size and type.
Does that resolve your problem ?

Comment: The conversion succeeded but I get the following error:
OpenCV Error: Sizes of input arguments do not match (The operation is neither 'array op array' (where arrays have the same size and the same type), nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op array') in compare

Comment: In the documentation of compare method :  `src1 : first input array or a scalar, when it is an array, it must have a single channel.` roi from ImgGray is a single-channel  Matrix, be sure OriginalImg is composed by only 1 channel too. By The Way C.Canberk Bac is right about features recognition isn't that simple that "compare" 2 ROI.

Answer (score 3):

0 - It is `compare`, not `detect`. It performs [per element comparison](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#compare)

1- You can not convert Rect to Mat, since one defines a 4 point geometrical shape whereas other defines a 3D matrix.

2- You can [crop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14365411/opencv-crop-image) your `Mat` with a `Rect`, and use that new `Mat` inside `compare`

3- Face recognition is not that simple. Please check out [this tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/facerec_tutorial.html).

Comment: The face recognition tutorial link is broken.