# How to crop image's borders opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, crop

I have an image with size 640x400 and i need to crop the defined borders, so 5 px from each side. 
So, the end image will 630x390 and without the borders.
What is the easiest way to do in with openCV in c++.

Comment: To be honest, this is like one of the first steps when using OpenCV, and definitely not worth asking for on Stack Overflow, since most "getting started" tutorials cover this topic. Also, have a look at the multiple options shown in the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.1/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#ad543b6bd296ae1247032c750af4718e1).

Comment: I understand you. The thing is that i am not learning it and i just needed to learn this thing. I spend around 20 minutes trying to find exactly this thing, but i didn't. 
Anyway, thank you for your reply.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [openCv crop image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14365411/opencv-crop-image) (Just searched SO for "crop opencv"...)

Comment: @DanMašek i already got an answer below. The question that you send is about cropping specific area with 4 points. I dont need it. I needed some kind of padding, and i got it and marked question as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple:

```
int padding = 5;
cv::Mat crop = cv::Mat(img, cv::Rect(padding, padding, img.cols - 2 * padding, img.rows - 2 * padding));
```